# Lint tool is throwing an error about bit width when adding two 10-bit unsigned numbers and assigning to a 11-bit net

Tags: verilog

My code:

```
module adder(a,b,result);
   input wire [9:0] a,b;
   output wire [10:0] result;
   assign result = a + b;
endmodule
```

My company recently changed policy to escalate the linting rule (W164a and W164b) mismatch of LHS and RHS bit widths from warnings to errors. Now I either have to waive these lines of code to tell the linting software not to freak out, or I have to prepend `1'b0` to both `a` & `b`.

What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The right approach is to discuss this situation with the people in your company who recently changed the policy.  Your Verilog code is very clean, and it is a common way to add numbers together.  Prepending `1'b0` to both `a` & `b` will result in code that is not commonly seen.

If you can not convince them to change this back to a warning, then you should waive these lines of code.

Comment: The reason stated for changing this was a lesson learnt in a previous project where they found some issue because they ignored this warning. I didn't discuss exactly what yet, but will do it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @nebuchadnezzar_II `found some issue because they ignored this warning` is unexpected.

Comment: The obvious error case is where _a_ or _b_ is a signed quantity with a negative value and the variable is not marked _signed_.

Comment: @greybeard, I agree and I'm not able to imagine such a situation. As grahamj42 points out, we do have the datapath switching in certain modes to signed representation.

Answer (score 8):

IMHO, padding 0's should *not* be an error. Only implicit casting with the potential loss of data should be a warning or error. Consider using SystemVerilog's explicit casting in place of waivers

```
assign result = 11'(a + b);
```